# BS4: Wrap range of siblings with new tags

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am on BeautifulSoup 4.8.1.

I want to augment a HTML file to highlight a section of interest.

Lets give an example. Assume I got

```html
<div> some preceding junk </div>
<div> BEGIN TRIGGER </div>
<div> Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
<div> sit amet, consetetur elitir </div>
<div> more clutter at the end </div>
<div> END TRIGGER </div>
```

I am already capable to extract a list containing the four `<div>` tags in the middle (i.e. from 'BEGIN TRIGGER' until 'clutter', including).

I want to produce the following output:

```html
<div> some preceding junk </div>
<p>
 <div> BEGIN TRIGGER </div>
 <div> Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
 <div> sit amet, consetetur elitir </div>
 <div> more clutter at the end </div>
</p>
<div> END TRIGGER </div>
```

How could I achieve this? I think knowing how to create a new sibling to a known bs4.element.Tag could be helpful, if wrapping the entire range 'atomically' is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I have tried this.Hope this will helps.
Using Regex first fine the element wanted add tag before and then `find_next_siblings`() to find until that.

Finally add new tag

then add all the div tag inside it.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div> some preceding junk </div>
<div> BEGIN TRIGGER </div>
<div> Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
<div> sit amet, consetetur elitir </div>
<div> more clutter at the end </div>
<div> END TRIGGER </div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
search=soup.find("div",text=re.compile('BEGIN'))
prev=search.find_previous_siblings('div')[0]

new_tag = soup.new_tag("p")
new_tag.append(str(search) +'\n')
for item in search.find_next_siblings('div'):

    if 'END TRIGGER' in item.text:
       lastement=item
       break;
    else:
        new_tag.append(str(item) + '\n')

finalsoup=str(prev) +'\n' + new_tag.prettify(formatter=None) + '\n' + str(lastement)

print(finalsoup)
```

**Output**:

```
<div> some preceding junk </div>
<p>
 <div> BEGIN TRIGGER </div>
 <div> Lorem ipsum dolor </div>
 <div> sit amet, consetetur elitir </div>
 <div> more clutter at the end </div>
</p>
<div> END TRIGGER </div>
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is more some tricky string manipulation instead of manipulating the actual HTML tree. Do you know how to achieve the latter?

Comment: Indeed this is tricky string manipulation.There is no generic way to achieve this kind of use cases.